# Webkit memory limit with -webkit-animation

Tags: css, animation, webkit

I'm faced with a memory issue, using `-webkit-animation`.

**Principle**

I want to animate a gradient background. As they are not animatable in keyframes, I put each background in a different `div`, and I'm playing with those `div` opacity and `z-index` :

- `.item01` is visible from 0% to 4%, starting to fade out at 0%
- `.item02` is visible from 0% to 8%, starting to fade out at 4% (and under `.item01`)
- `.item03` is visible from 0% to 12%, starting to fade out at 8% (and under `.item02`)
- ...

**Problem**

Only the 16 first animations work, on the 17th we just see a blank div, until the restart of all animations.

I noticed I don't have the problem using `-moz-animation` and Firefox, the issue only happens on Chrome, using `-webkit-`.

Depending of your viewport size, you'll be able to see more or less animations.

**Code**

*HTML*

```
<div class="item item-01">ITEM 01</div>
<div class="item item-02">ITEM 02</div>
<div class="item item-03">ITEM 03</div>
...
```

*CSS*

```
.item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}
.item-01 { 
  background: red; 
  z-index: 100; 
  -webkit-animation: item01 30s linear infinite;
}
.item-02 { 
  background: blue; 
  z-index: 96; 
  -webkit-animation: item02 30s linear infinite;
}
.item-03 { 
  background: red; 
  z-index: 92; 
  -webkit-animation: item03 30s linear infinite;
}
...
@-webkit-keyframes item01 { 0%, 100% {opacity: 1;}  4%, 99.999% {opacity: 0;} }
@-webkit-keyframes item02 { 4%, 100% {opacity: 1;}  8%, 99.999% {opacity: 0;} }
@-webkit-keyframes item03 { 8%, 100% {opacity: 1;} 12%, 99.999% {opacity: 0;} }
...
```

For the example purpose, I replaced gradient backgrounds by simple red/blue ones.

Any way to make this code work ?

**EDIT**
I updated my question, following to my recent found :

- Number of animations shown depends of your OS (Ubuntu seems to have better results than Win7)
- Number of animations shown depends of your viewport size

Comment: In my Chromium (last release version available from Ubuntu repositories) it is OK. There is no limit of 16.

Comment: Looking for details, we've found that it depends of your viewport size. The bigger it is, the lower is the limit. Should be a Chromium memory issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was indeed a webkit bug, that no longer exists for years.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the solution is to have only 2 divs, each with an animation.

The animation of the first div loads a background, transitions to opacity 0, changes the background, transitions to opacity 1, to oapcity 0 , changes the background, and so on.

The animation of the second div does the same, but with the even backgrounds